# Struts 1.3.10 and Commons Validator 1.4

Tags: java, struts, apache-commons

I'm migrating from Validator 1.3 to 1.4. And now the validation doesn't work ok. 
Is there some one who has used that "pair" and can help me to figure out?

Comment: How exactly is it failing?

Comment: it returns me to the input page without any errors.

Comment: works ok with commons-validator 1.3